# Nested Aura component Window.Location.reload() not refreshing whole web page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, aura

I have a Modal Aura component called another Aura component that is nested in a VF page. all of this is nested as a subcomponent in an app called VIP forms.

Currently when I close the modal it is set to fire `window.location.reload(true);`

The problem is that it only refreshes the components and not the entire web page. It seems this is due to the Parent VF page existing in only a segment of the site and not on the page directly. Is there a way to target the entire webpage with JS to refresh everything?

Not posting code because there is a lot and I don't think its needed for this question. Will post code If I have to.

Comment: have you tried to execute window.top.location.reload(true);?

Comment: @patlatus I receive error "Invalid SecureWindow API, top was blacklisted" looks like its not allowed

Comment: have you tried to run then `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` instead ?

Comment: @patlatus this also doesnt work correctly unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried to use messaging service to send a message from the component, which is nested in VF page to the component caller and execute $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();  inside a component caller context when a message from the callee component is received?